# can we make a software or solution( not a windows store app) on windows 8 using VS-2012

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

actually i working on a Application that is going to be build for windows 8 surface and desktop but we want this not to be on store but as a business solution. but i want my app to be tested by testers but i am not getting how to provide then my full package so that they can test it. any idea is appreciated.

Comment: So a Metro app but without it having to be in the appstore?

Comment: You mean [sideloading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx)?

Comment: @RogerRowland i mean i wantmy app to be tested on different computer..also this app is like a bussiness solution

Comment: @tanuj_loop on windows phone you have the beta option for the store but this seem to be not feasible on Windows RT as it say [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f4ce5ca0-58dd-4239-a545-e382a360d777/can-windows-store-app-also-provide-beta-testing-process-like-wp8), anyway for enterprise closed application I thinik you can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx)

Comment: It is pretty unlikely that you'll still be interested in a side-loading solution once you find out the cost of the required key.  Only pursue this if a number like three thousand doesn't make you blush.  Testing must be done by a temporary dev key, acquired when you build the app and valid only on the machine on which you build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012, with your Windows Store project selected, go to Project -> Store -> Create App Package...

Tell it that you do *not* want to upload the app package.

This will create a folder for your app that includes the .appx, the .cer, and a .psd (PowerShell script). Zip up this folder and send it to your testers. They just need to run the PowerShell script by right clicking it and clicking "Run in Powershell...". It will prompt them for a Developer's License (which they will need), but this will be retrieved automatically after signing in with their development account.